# Vegetable smoothies: are they good for you?

Tags: diet

I have been recently making vegetable smoothies using carrots and spinach. But is this healthy for me as I know having fruit smoothies contain broken down sugars and are bad for you. So is it good for health having vegetable smoothies instead of fruit ones?

I only have one carrot and a handful of cooked spinach once a day or so - is this in any way bad for health in the same regard as consuming too much sugar from fruit smoothies could be?

Comment: What is the question the raw spinach or the cooked spinach?

Comment: raw or cooked, are they good for you in smoothy form?

Comment: Against what are you basing your question vegetable,fruits are better then processed food. Please explain you question better. In away fresh is better then cooked less nutrients go away.

Comment: Putting vegetables in a blender isn't going to change their content, only their texture. So your question boils down to: Are carrots and spinach good for you? I don't know for sure but a guy named Popeye swears by them. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Vegetable smoothies are good to our health especially if you mix fruit too on it.
Smoothie doesn't require you to add processed sugar to taste better if you add fruits like banana and apples these are enough to sweeten your smoothie recipe. According to [AuthorityNutrition](https://authoritynutrition.com/is-fruit-good-or-bad-for-your-health/).

> “Sugar” is Bad… But it Depends on The Context
>
> Many people now believe that because added sugars are bad, the same
>   must apply to fruits, which also contain fructose.
>
> However… this is completely wrong because fructose is only harmful in
>   large amounts and it is almost impossible to overeat fructose by
>   eating fruit.

There's a lot of evidence that excessive intake of fructose can surely harm your body but it is not applicable for fruits because fruits are loaded with fiber, water and have significant chewing resistance. And therefore most fruits like apples will take a while to eat and digest, meaning that the fructose hits the liver slowly.

You can also add foods that are rich in protein and healthy fats like Coconut oil, almonds, and avocados. They [help to slow the release of sugar during digestion](http://simplegreensmoothies.com/low-sugar-fruits). If you are looking for other recipes try these [healthy smoothie recipes](https://behealthy.today/healthy-weight-loss-smoothies/) that are very helpful to your health.

Aside from that if you have an active lifestyle natural sugar won't affect your health.